# border css don't work in google chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, border

I got following css code from a tutorial to style an `hr` tag in firefox.

```
hr {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-image: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  border-color: #EEEEEE -moz-use-text-color #FFFFFF;
  border-style: solid none;
  border-color: #EEEEEE;
  border-width: 2px 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

[Result in picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwt703a0cqg443b/firefox.png)

I tried to do a similar thing for Chrome browser, and added the following code in `hr{}`:

```
-webkit-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -webkit-border-image: none;
  -webkit-border-left-colors: none;
  -webkit-border-right-colors: none;
  border-color:none;
  border-color: #EEEEEE -webkit-use-text-color #FFFFFF;
```

but it does not work in Chrome.

[Result in picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vtvsxk1pmpnujvy/chrome.png)

Please help me to do it in Chrome.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z2y5B/

Comment: @Ruddy It do't work for me. I now add the pictures of screenshoots in my Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've gone an odd way around stuff to just create borders.

If you just want borders, do something like this:

```
hr{
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#eee;
    border-width:2px;
}
```

Then add the other styles you want e.g `margin 10px;`. I see no point in adding browser specific code for a border.

If you want specific borders specific colours, you can use this:

```
border-top:1px solid #f00;
border-left:5px solid #00f;
border-right:2px solid #0f0;
border-bottom:10px solid #f0f;
```

Comment: Regardless of the odd way they made it, it still works.

Comment: Yeah, I don't dispute the fact it works, (works for me too), but it's a confusing way of doing it when it should be so much more simple. @Ruddy

Comment: @ Ruddy @ BeatAlex Are you got hr in chrome like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwt703a0cqg443b/firefox.png? But I got hr in chrome like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/vtvsxk1pmpnujvy/chrome.png.

Comment: got it 'border-top:1px solid #EEEEEE;
  border-bottom:10px solid #FFFFFF;  
  border-style: solid none;
  border-width: 2px 0;
  margin: 10px 0;'

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ShortCut

try this

border:4px #000 solid;

you do not need to add the -webkit and the rest in the new versions on browser

Comment: What you have there is not equivalent to what the OP has.